# Using XML in a Flex Website to Improve SEO

Tags: xml, noscript

I've got a Flex 3 site called [www.brainpinata.com](http://www.brainpinata.com) that's a trivia game. Basically, everything in the site is pulled from a database-- the questions, choices, and answers. So, unfortunately, Google doesn't index my content.

So, I'm trying to think of ways to improve the situation:

- If I took my database data and put it in an XML file which was in the website's root directory, would this work? Would it violate any Google policy? (The info would be the same as in the db-- so nothing shady.) Would I have to "wire" the XML into my site or would it be enough to just have the XML sitting in the root directory?
- Another idea is to use the noscript tag and load the XML content there. As I understand it Google indexes content that people who have Javascript turned off would see. I know Flex/Actionscript 3, and unfortunately, I don't know how to load XML content with HTML. Does anyone know of an example where a Flex site uses XML for the noscript content?

Answer (score 1):

I would take a look at this:
http://www.seomoz.org/ugc/seo-friendly-flex-websites

Comment: Oh, and using XML in no way violates any policy of Google. Afterall, XHTML is a derivative of XML. Your problem is that Flex websites are built in flash, which Google can't read.

Comment: Hi Adam, Thank you for the link. That's an interesting idea. I'm not sure if I would be able to implement it, though. (I don't have any javascript skills. I don't know XSLT, although that looks straight forward. But, I've got another idea.  Would it help Google index more content if I put a link in the Flex project to a static XML file of the questions and answers and used XSLT to list them in a table? Do you think that it would help? Or is it a bad idea. Thanks for all your help.